# How to insert data to web API using Angular 5

Tags: angular, rest, httpclient

I am new developper in Angular . I have a api service.But when i make insert data , i added empty data on my table. id increases on my screen but data does not add to my api.Where do I mistake ? I shared my codes.Also there is an opportunity to take City info from dropdownList. Could you help me at this issue ? 
I can add my project to your answers in Angular 5 or 6.

-My Bank model

```
export class {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  contactName: string;
  contactSurname: string;
  contactPhone: string;
  secondContactPhone: string;
  bankLogo: any;
  town: Town;
  city: City;
}
```

-My City model

```
export class City{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  code: number;
}
```

-My bank service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient/*,HttpHeaders */} from "@angular/common/http";
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { Bank } from "../models/bank";
import { Observable } from '../../node_modules/rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError,map,tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class BankService {

      private bankURL = 'exampleURL';
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


addContent(newContent:Bank):Observable<Bank>{

  return this.http.post<Bank>(this.bankURL,newContent).pipe(
    tap((bank:Bank) => console.log('inserted bank = ${JSON.stringify(bank)}')), // $json.stringify does not work
    catchError(error=> of(new Bank()))
  );
}
}
```

-My Bank Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bank } from '../models/bank';
import { BankService } from './bank.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bank',
  templateUrl: './bank.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bank.component.css'],
  providers:[BankService]
})
export class BankComponent implements OnInit {
  title="Bank";
  bank:Bank[];
  constructor(private bankService:BankService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  add(  id: string,
    name: string,
    address: string,
    contactName: string,
    contactSurname: string,
    contactPhone: string,
    secondContactPhone: string,
    bankLogo: any):void{

      const newUser : Bank = new Bank();
      newUser.name=name;
      newUser.address=address;
      newUser.contactName=contactName;
      newUser.contactSurname=contactSurname;
      newUser.contactPhone=contactPhone;
      newUser.secondContactPhone=secondContactPhone;
      newUser.bankLogo=bankLogo;
      this.bankService.addContent(newUser).subscribe(insertedUser=>{this.bank.push(insertedUser);});
    }  
}
```

-Component.html

```
<div style ="text-align: left;">
 <table style="width: 300px">
   <tr>
     <td>new name:</td>
     <td><input #name placeholder="name"></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<tr>
  <button (click)="add(name.value);name.value='';">add</button>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the `newContent` before its posted to the post call,  if not then  directly do a `map(res=>console.log(res))` else if it absolutely necessary , then  change this line  `console.log('inserted bank = ${JSON.stringify(bank)}')` to `console.log('inserted bank',bank);`

Comment: ı changed console.log('inserted bank = ${JSON.stringify(bank)}') to console.log('inserted bank',bank) but where will i write  map(res=>console.log(res))  ?

Comment: Hi, check out the answer below @Emre Sert

Answer (score 0):

```
    return this.http.post<Bank>(this.bankURL,newContent).pipe(
    map((res) => console.log('inserted bank', res)), // $json.stringify does not work
    catchError(error=> of(new Bank()))
  );
```

If you don't have any data that needs to change then this should suffice.